# What would be the name for government for, from, and by

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, meaning, word-request, ancient-greek

1. The people
2. Shareholders
3. The king
4. Investors
5. Customers
6. Tax payers

Plus explanation. From sources, I've heard that those are

1. Democracy
2. Metochocracy
3. Monarchy
4. Ependocracy
5. Pelatarchy
6. What?

I may be wrong.

Would anyone please correct or confirm 1-5 and answer 6

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions in one here. I'd recommend more specificity: pick one of your questions, ideally one that's specifically about Latin and Greek rather than about the English descendants, and narrow your focus to that one.

Comment: The list wasn't clearly seen. I didn't notice that. Basically I am asking for a greek world for government for, by, from those 6 things. With 5 I already have a good guess but I think it's better that it's all in one question so people can see the answer to all 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words that end in -cracy are from Greek -κρατία, which is κράτος 'power' + an abstract noun suffix -ία. The ones in -archy are analysable as ending in -αρχία, or ἄρχω 'to rule' + the same suffix.

In **democracy**, the initial word is δῆμος 'people'; no surprises there.

**Metochocracy** uses μέτοχος 'partner, accomplice' (μετά 'with' (in this case) + ἔχω 'to hold' + -ος, a noun-forming suffix), which is certainly a defensible choice.

**Monarchy** uses μόνος 'only' and is obviously a cromulent word. (Actually it's not μόνος + -αρχία but μόναρχος lit. 'only ruler' + -ία, which explains the semantics a little better.)

**Ependocracy** looks like it's built on ἐπενδύω, but that means 'to put on (a piece of clothing) over (another piece of clothing)'; only in modern Greek does it mean 'to invest'. A reasonable Classical alternative might be προστίθημι, which has a basic meaning of 'to put to' and from there 'to augment' and in the medial 'to associate with', which I think works. The derived agent noun, προσθέτης, is not actually attested in a meaning anywhere close to 'investor', but I think a coinage like **prosthetocracy** is defensible for 'rule by investors'—an ugly word for an ugly concept.

**Pelatarchy** is built on modern Greek again; πελάτης is 'one who approaches' in Classical Greek (ultimately from πέλας 'near'). ὠνητής is a Classical word meaning 'buyer': **onetocracy** /oʊnɪˈtɒkɹəsi/.

Your last one is kind of tricky because the usual Classical words for tax are τέλος or φορά, which are very ambiguous out of context. Here modern Greek *can* help: the modern word for taxpayer is φορολογούμενος, the medio-passive present participle of φορολογέω, which Classically meant 'to levy tribute from', i.e. 'one from whom tribute is levied'. That works just fine: **phorologoumenocracy**.

Obviously none of these except democracy and monarchy will be particularly transparent to anyone.